# separate context from block in swift

Tags: swift, closures, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to create a convenience method to add a notification observer:

```
func subscribe<T: AnyObject>(block: (T) -> (NSNotification) -> (),
    at: T, to: AnyObject? = nil, on: String) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(on,
            object: to, queue: mainQueue) { [weak at] notification in
                if let at = at {
                    block(at)(notification)
                }
        }
}
```

where you can subscribe to a notification via:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    subscribe(MyVC.method, at: self, to: kNotificationName, from: notificationObject)
}
```

but what I would like to be able to do is something like:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    subscribe(self.method, to: kNotificationName, from: notificationObject)
}
```

and somehow extract the context so that I can reference it as weak to avoid retaining the self instance in case it's dropped.

I'd even appreciate an answer in obj-c.